# stuck screw now stripped when trying to remove outdoor faucet handle

Tags: screws

My outdoor faucet is leaking. I was trying to remove the handle so I could replace the washers. I could not get the screw to budge. Now I have stripped the stuck screw. What do I do?

Comment: Is the screw head flush with the handle or is it round and sticking up from the handle?

Comment: It is round and flush with the handle.

Answer (score 1):

You could drill a small hole straight into the screw from above and use a screw extractor (or "ez-out"), it can be a difficult operation with varying degrees of success depending on experience and skill.

[image]

Or you could break off the handle, you could then get a grip on the protruding screw with pliers to remove it. The problem is you may or may not be able to procure a replacement handle.

You should probably start looking at replacing the entire faucet just in case your efforts to remove the screw are unsuccessful.

Comment: +1 to replacement. Get a nice ball valve hose bib and avoid washers for the foreseeable future.